# How to force OpenGL to draw before the app becomes visible?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, opengl-es

My OpenGL app launches dark and then some time later OpenGL begins drawing. I call drawing methods immediately upon launch though.

Is there a way to force it to draw at least one frame before the app turns visible? Or must I use a splash screen until OpenGL had a chance to draw? Is there a callback that can be used to figure out it has drawn?

Comment: Did you check that you're actually not doing some long-running task for a few seconds in the `applicationDidFinishLaunching` method?

Answer (score 0):

You have to use a Default image (splash screen), or iOS will display a black window before your app finishes initializing.

Comment: The default.png is not meant to be a splash screen.

Comment: @JustSid : That is Apple's recommendation.  But they currently approve tons of apps that use it as a splash as well, as is common on other platforms.